# Apply the focus rectangle to a child element

Tags: wpf, xaml, focus

In a control I'm currently working on, when an item is focused, the default focus rectangle spans the entire row and all of its visible child items. I know how to hide that. But I still want such a focus indicator when the item has the keyboard focus. I've read about the IsKeyboardFocused property but that is true also when the item was clicked by the mouse. So I guess I need to use the FocusVisualStyle somehow. But I can't figure out how.

Here's what the default focus looks like:

[image]

And this is what it should like:

[image]

Here's my XAML code for the control template:

```
<Border ...>
    <ContentPresenter FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"
        Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.Header}"
        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate}"
        ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderStringFormat}"
        ContentSource="Header"
        Name="PART_Header" .../>
</Border>
<!-- Additional border glare inside the item -->
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#80ffffff" Margin="1"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True" CornerRadius="2"/>
<!-- Focus rectangle inside the item -->
<Rectangle StrokeDashArray="1 2" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="2"
    Visibility="Hidden" Name="FocusRectangle"
    FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}"/>
```

There is already a focus rectangle in my XAML that is invisible by default. With FocusVisualStyle or anything, it shall be made visible. But I didn't manage to do that. It's either visible at any focus, or never.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for the issue. It looks the same to me, but I'm not completely sure whether it's *the* correct way to do it. I'm using the FocusRectangle from above and care for showing and hiding it myself.

Here's the trigger that manages the focus rectangle visibility:

```
<!-- Show the focus rectangle when the item is focused -->
<MultiTrigger>
  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Property="Controls:TreeViewExItem.IsKeyboardMode" Value="True"/>
    <Condition Property="Controls:TreeViewExItem.IsFocused" Value="True"/>
  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
  <Setter TargetName="FocusRectangle" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
</MultiTrigger>
```

Then I have added a new property to the TreeViewExItem that indicates whether the last input came from the mouse or the keyboard. This could possibly be extended to touch or stylus, but I don't have such devices to test.

```
public static DependencyProperty IsKeyboardModeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsKeyboardMode",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(TreeViewExItem),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, null));

public bool IsKeyboardMode
{
    get
    {
        return (bool) GetValue(IsKeyboardModeProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(IsKeyboardModeProperty, value);
    }
}
```

This property is passed to each item from the parent control through binding:

```
<!-- Pass on the TreeViewEx' IsKeyboardMode value to each item because
  we couldn't access it otherwise in the triggers -->
<Setter Property="IsKeyboardMode"
  Value="{Binding (Controls:TreeViewEx.IsKeyboardMode),
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource
      AncestorType={x:Type Controls:TreeViewEx}}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

The same IsKeyboardMode property is added to the TreeViewEx parent control and here comes my magic:

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
    if (!IsKeyboardMode)
    {
        IsKeyboardMode = true;
        //Debug.WriteLine("Changing to keyboard mode from PreviewKeyDown");
    }
}

protected override void OnPreviewKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
    if (!IsKeyboardMode)
    {
        IsKeyboardMode = true;
        //Debug.WriteLine("Changing to keyboard mode from PreviewKeyUp");
    }
}

protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
    if (IsKeyboardMode)
    {
        IsKeyboardMode = false;
        //Debug.WriteLine("Changing to mouse mode");
    }
}
```

This reacts on the preview events of keyboard and mouse to set the appropriate input mode. Only if the last input came from a keyboard, the focus rectangle is visible.